# Как отобразить символ & в TextView?

Tags: android, xml, textview

В string.xml нужно добавить строку в которой содержится символ &, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать ее в TextView, но данный символ подчеркивается красной линией. Как его записать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте спец. символ `&amp;`.

```
 <string name="my_string">&amp;</string>
```

Другие подобные символы можете посмотреть на [этой](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php) странице.